# why does DNS issue occur everytime i restart my ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualbox, dns

I face DNS issue sometimes in my Ubuntu Server 14.04 version. In order to solve that I follow the procedure mentioned **[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628398/dns-issue-in-ubuntu-14-04)**.

Unable to resolve the DNS:

```
#ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com
```

But internet connectivity is available:

```
# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=15.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=15.7 ms
```

So I do repeat the same procedure everytime to resolve the DNS:

```
# resolvconf -u
# service network-manager restart
network-manager stop/waiting
network-manager start/running, process 9522

# ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.197.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from maa03s20-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.46): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=23.5 ms
64 bytes from maa03s20-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.197.46): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=13.2 ms
```

So my question is **does the procedure suggested is a temporary one as I need to repeat the procedure whenever I face the problem**?

**What should be done to not to face this again**?

EDIT1 : This is how my resolv.conf looks like:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 172.24.100.50
nameserver 10.1.100.50
search <mycompany_name>.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The DNS resolution is as dumm as they come: it looks in the /etc/resolv.conf for the nameserver line. In your case it should look like this (after a reboot):

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

If the file looks different, the DNS information comming from the DHCP is most likley wrong (http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#nat_host_resolver_proxy, assuming your host also uses the 8.8.8.8 DNS).